# Contracts in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, interface, inversion-of-control, laravel-5

Interfaces I understand the reasons for. Single responsibility I understand the reasoning. Basically I do understand why the 'contract' path has been chosen, I'm just struggling with understanding the implementation.

For example the docs give us this example:

```
<?php namespace App\Orders;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository as Cache;

class Repository {

    /**
     * Create a new repository instance.
     *
     * @param  Cache  $cache
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Cache $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

}
```

If i were to replace the laravel native cache driver with, let's say, a third party, framework agnostic cache driver, would I then have to write an adapter to adhere to Laravel 5.0 cache contract?

Comment: Contracts are interfaces. The reasoning behind them is the **D** in **SOLID**: dependency inversion (depend on an abstraction rather than a concrete implementation). This [Laracasts Video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/7) explains very well the Laravel Contracts and the reasoning behind them.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Let me know if there's further questions : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking [Binding Interfaces To Implementations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations).

#### How to bind an implementation to an interface?

```
$this->app->bind('App\Contracts\EventPusher', 'App\Services\PusherEventPusher');
```

#### And where does Laravel itself bind the default implementations?

In ['Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php'](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1026), it told the container what are the aliases for an abstract keyword:

```
'cache' => ['Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory'],
```

this way, when you write either

```
$this->app->make('Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager')
```

or

```
$this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory')
```

it's basically the same as

```
$this->app->make('cache')
```

And in Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider.php, it told the container what are the real bindings to the abstract keyword:

```
$this->app->singleton('cache', function ($app) {
    return new CacheManager($app);
});
```

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Hi @尤川豪, I saw the list of implementations bindings in Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php, but that list also include an alias "key" for each one. This is what confuses me - since I know those aliases are also defined in each framwork service provider (in the 'register' method) that are loaded in laravel/config/app.php - how do you explain the fact that they are defined twice?

Comment: it's concrete classes in Application.php, and it's Facades classes in app.php?

Comment: that's true, but I am talking about the service providers in app.php, they are loaded there and if you look inside each one, each one defines their own alias as well there. look for example in [Illuminate/Cache/CacheServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheServiceProvider.php#L24) - the 'cache' word is defined there to be 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager' - just like in [Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1025)

Comment: @amosmos the 'cache' word is actually stored in the container's $bindings property, and this happened in the CacheServiceProvider. In the Application.php, the 'cache' word is stored in the container's $aliases property, it's just telling the container that if anyone looks for 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager' or 'Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Factory', they are asking for the implementtation of 'cache'.

Comment: @amosmos so, to your question, the real 'binding' stuff is actually happened in the service provider. the Application.php' just defines what are the aliases.

Comment: @amosmos sorry I think my original answer is confusing and misleading. let me update it.

Comment: @amosmos besides, you might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709013/laravel-core-why-does-laravel-store-aliases-multiple-times